# How to get a notification after AWS Cloudfront invalidation is completed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a way, where I can get notification using RESTAPI call, after the AWS Cloud-front invalidation is completed?

Comment: If only somebody would make an app that would poll the APIs and give OS notifications for CloudFront deployment status and invalidations...

Comment: This question was asked a few years ago. Anyone find a good way to get this notification?

Answer (score 3):

You can't get a "notification" (pushed or triggered).

You can only poll for the status of existing invalidations using the [`Get Invalidation`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/GetInvalidation.html) request from the CloudFront API.

Comment: Anything new you've run across in the past couple years on this topic?

Comment: @Greg nothing new to report.  This still requires polling.

Comment: Still nothing new? The solution here seems like a classic use case for a message queue such as https://aws.amazon.com/sqs

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Hi Michael - I'm guessing there is still no alternative to polling? Appreciate this is quite a niche request, so wouldn't expect AWS to implement such an event, but nevertheless, worth asking...

Comment: @BenCarey not that I'm aware of.  I would assume Amazon EventBridge would be what they would use if this were supported, but their [Events from AWS Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-service-event.html) page doesn't mention CloudFront.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - very frustrating, thank you anyway